# Консольная графическая библиотека для python

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите библиотеку. Нужно, чтобы она делала что-то подобное:

```
Canvas=Canvas(w,h)
Canvas.Line(x,y)
........
Canvas.SaveToJpg(filename)
```

т.е. создаем холст, рисуем на нем примитивами а потом сохраняем его как графический файл

Comment: Непонятно при чем здесь термин "консольная".

Comment: Логику включите

Comment: Включена у него логика, чем отличается консольная библиотека от не консольной? В консоли обычный интерпетатор, тот же самый, который и файлы читает.
Canvas есть в tkinter, можно ли сохранять изображения не знаю.
Если вы юзаете python 3 ищите не pil, а pillow.

Comment: Консольная означает что для результата не требуется гуй. Подушка не нужна, проблема давно решена

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте PIL. Если нужно рисовать графики и прочие вещи для визуализации данных, используйте matplotlib.